# Rest Call in not working

Tags: java, rest, jsp, jstl, scriptlet

I am trying to consume a rest call, which takes location of file in os.
In return the rest call simulates a download of the file.

bellow is the code

```
<div class="form-container">
        <h1>Welcome to CoinPay</h1>

        Click on below links to download Coin.<br /><br />

         <a href="<c:url value='/download/<%=request.getParameter("dest") %>' />">Coin Mobile
            Application</a>


    </div>
```

In parameter `"dest"` values is `D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk`.

The rest calls defination is given bellow

```
@RequestMapping(value="/download/{dest}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void downloadFile(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("dest") String dest) throws IOException {
}
```

for some reason the link created by `href` is not able to access the rest call.

How should I do this. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create links like `/download?dest=testDest` you can use `<c:param>`.

```
<c:url value="/download" var="myURL">
   <c:param name="dest" value="${dest}" />
</c:url>

<a href="${myURL}" />${myURL}</a>
```

And Please change your controller.[@RequestParam](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestparam)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadFile(HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam("dest") String dest) {
     .......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As your `dest` variable has forward slashes in its value so first you need to enable slashes in path param using annotation like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "download/{dest:.+}" })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but its not working for me